# Calculating the years needed to double energy in the system

Tags: proof-verification, applications

Using the following information:

- The EROI of corn ethanol is 1.3:1
- Gross system energy per unit out = $EROI / [EROI-1]$
- This means for each extra unit of energy produced, 4.33 units of energy were produced, 3.33 of which were used to produce the extra unit
- You can only grow corn once per year

How many years do you have to grow corn to double your energy? Would that be 3.33 years?

Comment: I am not sure what tags to use

Comment: It took me awhile to figure out the second equation and the third result. I am trying to calculate this for an article I am writing. I just want to make sure this is correct and I fully understand this!

Answer (score 0):

EROI is energy output divided by energy input, which I understand to be 1.3 in this case.

Suppose you start with one unit of energy. Note that $1.3^0 = 1$.

After one cycle of growing corn and making ethanol etc., your energy will be $1.3 \cdot 1 = 1.3 = 1.3^1$.

After two cycles, your energy will be $1.3 \cdot 1.3 = 1.3^2 = 1.69$.

After three cycles, you will have $1.3 \cdot 1.3^2 = 1.3^3 = 2.197 > 2$.

---

The general solution is that after $n$ cycles (where $n$ is an integer) you will have $1.3^n$ times the original energy. To solve when the energy has grown to $k$ times the original, you need to solve the equation $1.3^n = k$. Take a logarithm of both sides to get
$$
n = \frac{\log k}{\log 1.3} = \log_{1.3} k.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of years needed to double the energy is $$\log_{4/3} 2 = \frac {\log 2} {\log 4 - \log 3} = 2.40942083965\cdots$$